# How to convert Seq[Column] into a Map[String,String] and change value?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, data-structures, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to Scala and Spark and I'm struggling to do the following,
I'm trying to convert a Seq into a Map and at the same time, modify the value when I'm converting the sequence by adding a "_suffix" like so:

```
val columns = Seq($"col2",$"col3")
val map = columns.map(t => t.toString() -> t.toString()+"_suffix").toMap
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
scala> val map = columns.map(t => t.toString() -> t.toString()+"_suffix").toMap
<console>:25: error: Cannot prove that String <:< (T, U).
       val map = columns.map(t => t.toString() -> t.toString()+"_suffix").toMap
```

Furthermore, the `.map` result returns the following:

```
scala> val map = columns.map(t => t.toString() -> t.toString()+"_suffix")
map: Seq[String] = List((col2,col2)_suffix, (col3,col3)_suffix)
```

And this is what I'm trying to produce:

```
map: Seq[(String, String)] = List((col2,col2_suffix), (col3,col3_suffix)
```

So I can ultimately convert it into a Map:

```
map: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(col2 -> col2_suffix, col3 -> col3_suffix)
```

I'm pretty stuck trying to achieve this, any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have done is correct, just add some parenthesis and it will work:

```
columns.map(t => t.toString() -> (t.toString() + "_suffix")).toMap
```

---

As you can see from your results, the `"_suffix"` is added to the string of the tuple, i.e.

```
(col2,col2)_suffix
```

What you want to do is add the string to the second element only, hence the parenthesis is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your supposed input($ to be removed before quotes as shown in question):

```
scala> val columns = Seq("col2","col3")
columns: Seq[String] = List(col2, col3)
```

In your code there is no need to use `toString()` method 
on each string as they are already `strings`, 
and use map as below:

```
val map = columns.map(t => (t,t+"_suffix")).toMap
```

**In Scala REPL:**

```
scala> val map = columns.map(t => (t,t+"_suffix"))
map: Seq[(String, String)] = List((col2,col2_suffix), (col3,col3_suffix))

scala> val map = columns.map(t => (t,t+"_suffix")).toMap
map: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(col2 -> col2_suffix, col3 -> col3_suffix)
```